# printing array by foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays

Can I print all of the elements of an array in one go in foreach loop ?
I tried this but dont understand this list fully.

```
foreach ($array as list ($a,$b,$c,$d,$e))
                    {
                    echo "<td>".$a."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$b."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$c."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$d."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$e."</td>";                     
                    }
```

Thank you.

here is the sample of array

```
Array ( [0] => sajan sahoo [1] => PHP [2] => JS [3] => JQ [4] => Mysql )
```

Comment: Show a sample of the array you're working with: the `$array as list (...)` syntax does work in the most recent versions of PHP (>= 5.5)

Answer (score 0):

it is rather:

```
list($a,$b,$c,$d,$e) = $array;

echo "<td>".$a."</td>";
echo "<td>".$b."</td>";
echo "<td>".$c."</td>";
echo "<td>".$d."</td>";
echo "<td>".$e."</td>";
```

Or:

```
$output = "<td>";
$output .= implode("</td><td>",$array);
$output .= "</td>";
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use var_dump(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

> ```
> void var_dump ( mixed $expression [, mixed $... ] )
> ```
>
> This function displays structured information about one or more
>   expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are
>   explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

Also interesting:

> Keep in mind if you have xdebug installed it will limit the var_dump()
>   output of array elements and object properties to 3 levels deep.
>
> To change the default, edit your xdebug.ini file and add the
>   folllowing line: xdebug.var_display_max_depth=n
>
> More information here: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/display

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I agree and made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a multidimensional array ( by the look of the 'foreach( $array...' t looks like you are, then perhaps something like the following? You will see that the variables $a,$b etc have been replaced with strings in the example

```
$array=array(
    array('one','two','three','four','five'),
    array('six','seven','eight','nine','ten'));

function td( &$item, $key ){
    echo '<td>'.$item.'</td>';  
}
array_walk_recursive( $array,'td');
```

Answer (score 0):

For your sample array,

```
$arr = Array ( [0] => sajan sahoo [1] => PHP [2] => JS [3] => JQ [4] => Mysql );
```

If you want to print all array at once you can do just by echoing array key as,

```
echo "<td>".$arr[0]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$arr[1]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$arr[2]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$arr[3]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$arr[4]."</td>";
```

in that case why you need foreach loop.

But if you meant about nested loop then in PHP 5.5 you can do so by using list with foreach as

```
$array = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
];

foreach ($array as list($a, $b)) {
    // $a contains the first element of the nested array,
    // and $b contains the second element.
    echo "A: $a; B: $b\n";
}
```

then it will output as

```
A: 1; B: 2
A: 3; B: 4
```

Refer the PHP official [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#control-structures.foreach.list) for more information.